# What Windows Shell PROPERTYKEY ID's are available?

Tags: winapi, com, windows-shell

I've found various COM and Shell Interfaces like `IFolderView2::GetGroupBy()` that refers to a `PROPERTYKEY`.   Where can one find all the build-in property keys available that are related to the Windows shell?

TIA!!

Comment: You can enumerate them using the `PSEnumeratePropertyDescriptions()` function.

Comment: [Windows Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props) has a list of system-defined properties.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'd mark yours as the answer but it's a comment.

Comment: Post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props) has a list of system-defined properties.

Comment: Not very useful for coding, though!